# Eclipse Maven: Run configuration - Start two servers

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to use the gwt-maven-archetype [from here](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) and now after I imported the project I'd like Eclipse Maven to run:

1. `mvn gwt:codeserver -pl *-client -am`  to start the codeserver and
2. `mvn tomcat7:run -pl *-server -am -Denv=dev` to run tomcat server

How can I tell Eclipse to do that for me?

Best regards.

Comment: I would suggest creating run configuration for each command. Than you can start it one by one

Comment: @eugener Is there a way to combine these somehow? To tell either Maven or Eclipse to run those two servers?

Comment: if you have maven installed externally, you can create an external tools configuration

Comment: I've been told the [GWT Plugin for Eclipse](https://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/) (fork of Google Plugin for Eclipse) can do that; I have no idea if/how it supports multi-module projects though.

Answer (score 0):

You could establish an extra "run" project and [use](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508070131/http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) the [exec-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22exec-maven-plugin%22) in it's POM.